# Turning dictionary values into different lists - the dictionary values are tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'2007-10-21': ('32', '10', '78', '69'), '2007-10-28': ('32', '10', '79', '78'), '2011-07-10': ('62', '46', '67', '54')...}
```

I want to create a function to correctly sort it by date (dictionary keys) and then split the items of the tuples in different lists, combining each index of the tuples in the same list (all the first items in one list, all the second items in another list, and so on). Note that the number of lists must be the same number of tuple items and the number of list items must have the same number of tuples within the dict. In the above example I would have the following correctly sorted lists:

```
List 1: [32,32,62]
List 2: [10,10,46]
List 3: [78,79,67]
List 4: [69,78,54]
```

I'm using a code that is nailing it for the first list, however it is not creating the next lists, as you can see below:

```
def dict2manylists(*dicts):
"""
Receives dictionaries with tuples as values and turns it into different lists correctly sorted
:param dic: dictionaries with many different values grouped in touples
:return: different lists correctly sorted
"""


for i in dicts:
    sorted_dict=sorted(i.items())
    list=[]
    for y in range(len(sorted_dict)):
        x=0
        list.append(sorted_dict[y][1][x])
        x+=1
    print list
```

Can someone help?

Comment: How are the lists expected to be sorted?

Comment: They should be sorted by date, which are the dictionary keys

Comment: Can I confirm that `list 3` should be `[67, 79, 78]` and `list 4` should be `[54, 78, 69]`?

Comment: @Ogaday just corrected the lists, they were wrongly sorted, sorry about that. they should not be sorted in a reversed fashion but in normal order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as Kasramvd, but sorted by date.

```
zip(*(dct[i] for i in sorted(dct)))
```

Comment: by the way, the lists were wrongly sorted, sorry about that @pacholik. just corrected it. it should not be in a reversed manner but in regular sort.

Comment: `dct` is dict like the one you provided.

Comment: Ok, just remove `reverse=True` then.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to screw it like this, simple use `dict.values()` to access to dict values and use `zip` to get the columns, and then you can use a list comprehension to loop over the columns and sort them:

```
>>> d = {'2007-10-21': ('32', '10', '78', '69'), '2007-10-28': ('32', '10', '79', '78'), '2011-07-10': ('62', '46', '67', '54')}

>>> [sorted(x,reverse=True) for x in zip(*d.values())]
[['62', '32', '32'], 
 ['46', '10', '10'], 
 ['79', '78', '67'], 
 ['78', '69', '54']]
```

If you want to sort based on the date you can convert the string date to datetime using `datetime.strptime()` function and sort the dict items based on this field then use zip to get the columns:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> zip(*[j for i,j in sorted(d.items(),key = lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0],'%Y-%m-%d'))])
[('32', '32', '62'), ('10', '10', '46'), ('78', '79', '67'), ('69', '78', '54')]
```

Comment: This sorts by value, not by date, I believe. He wants the nested list elements to be sorted by the dates of their respective keys.

Comment: @Ogaday Yes, It seems to. Tanks for attention.

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'values' of 'dict' object needs an argument

Comment: by the way, the lists were wrongly sorted, sorry about that @Kasramvd. just corrected it. it should not be in a reversed manner but in regular sort.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think this is essentially the same as @pacholik's. He got in there first.

```
[list(z) for z in zip(*[d[key] for key in sorted(d.keys(), reverse=True)])]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: It works for me in both python 3.4 and python 2.7. The one mistake I made was the violate the built-in `dict`. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to put those beautiful solutions to work (I'm a Python beginner and for some reason it didn't work for me but I'm sure they are good and functional).

I found a way to get what I want. For sure is not the most elegant solution but it worked:

```
for i in dicts:
    sorted_dict=sorted(i.items())
    for item in range(len(sorted_dict[1][1])):
        list=[]
        for y in range(len(sorted_dict)):
            list.append(sorted_dict[y][1][item])
        print list
```